# How to escape % when referring to a resource field in twig?

Tags: twig

I'm using twig and need to have access to a resource field named "%". 
When I try this in the twig template I get an error:

```
{{ something.something2.%}}
```

Is there any way to escape the `%` ?

Comment: Did you try `something["something2"]["%"]`?

Answer (score 0):

So i realize this is an old question but i just found the answer to it.

You have to use the attribute function:

```
{{ attribute(something.something2, '%') }}
```

This is used to get the value of a property with any special characters that twig my otherwise interpret to mean other things.

You can check out the documentation for the function here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html